# (SwiftUI) Function for saving item to a list only displaying one option from an array out of four?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to build something of a dummy book store/shopping app.
Something about this function is only displaying one option out of four written in an array...but I'm not sure why? Essentially, what this does is allow a user to add this to a list out of a searchable selection...except it's somehow decided that all of the options are only the first one?

The Function itself:

```
func addToWishList() {
guard !search.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
return
}
let NewBook = NewBook.self
viewModel.featureissues.append(NewBook)
search = ""
}
}
```

The Class with published var:

class ComicIssueCardViewModel: ObservableObject {

```
@Published var featureissues = [
book(id: 1, title: "Book One", image: "IMG1", details: " Sample Details"),
book(id: 2, title: "Book Two", image: "IMG2", details: "Sample Details"),
book(id: 3, title: "Book Three", image: "IMG3", details: "Sample Details"),
book(id: 4, title: "Book Four", image: "IMG4" "Sample Details")
]
}
```

Also, the UUID struct:

```
struct featureissues: Identifiable{
var id = UUID()
var title: String
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: "is only displaying one option out of four written in an array" -- you aren't showing any code that displays anything, so it's hard to say what's wrong. In general, you may want to consider adopting standard Swift naming conventions. For example, types should start with capital letters and be camel cased. So, `FeatureIssues` instead of `featureissues`. Then, naming your variables the *same thing* as your types can lead to a lot of confusion. So, `@Published var featureissues` might just be `@Published var issues`. Same issue with `let NewBook = NewBook.self`, which is quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that; I'm still in the learning stages and...well, it helped me keep track of things better. Essentially, the NewBook is the @Published var I've provided there. The function only displays "Book One" rather than all four options depending on what title is typed in.

Comment: "The function only displays" -- there isn't any code that "displays" anything in what you've included. I agree with the first comment that it would be good see a [mre].

Comment: @Published var --references an array (var NewBook: book) set up on a separate file. Information is used across multiple views, including this one.  viewModel.featureissues.append(NewBook)
      search = ""
            }  seems to be the problem area.

Comment: You need to add your code to the question. Stop trying to explain it in comments and actually post all of the structs and classes you are referencing. Someone should be able to come along, copy the code to Xcode, run it and see what is going on.